# WPF Tables within FixedDocument

Tags: wpf, documentviewer, fixeddocument, fixedpage

I was wondering if it is possible adding a WPF-Table within a FixedDocument/FixedPage. It seems, as if it is not supported by default.

Is there some kind of workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post series explains how to do multipage WPF reports with tables:
http://janrep.blog.codeplant.net/post/WPF-Multipage-Reports-Part-I.aspx

You can also use [WPF Reports](http://wpfreports.codeplex.com/) (open-source) to do multi-page tables and much more.

Comment: the first link is dead.